# HIVE - quoteChar serde doesn't work

Tags: csv, hive

I've a CSV file like that:

> ""9998"";""714144"";""frwiki-20131107-pages-meta-history2.xml"";""Ripchip
>   Bot""
>   ""10000"";""195090"";""frwiki-20131107-pages-meta-history2.xml"";""TXiKiBoT""
>   ""10002"";""265154"";""frwiki-20131107-pages-meta-history2.xml"";""Jimmy44""

I try to create an external table with it:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE titi(username string,id int, revisionid int, fileName string) row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
    with serdeproperties("separatorChar" = "\;"
    , "quoteChar" = "\"\"")
    stored as textfile
    LOCATION '/contributor';
```

But as a result I've :

```
hive> select * from titi limit 10;
OK
��"9998""       ""714144""      ""frwiki-20131107-pages-meta-history2.xml""     ""Ripchip Bot""
        NULL    NULL    NULL
"10000""        ""195090""      ""frwiki-20131107-pages-meta-history2.xml""     ""TXiKiBoT""
        NULL    NULL    NULL
"10002""        ""265154""      ""frwiki-20131107-pages-meta-history2.xml""     ""Jimmy44""
        NULL    NULL    NULL
"10004""        """"    ""frwiki-20131107-pages-meta-history2.xml""     """"
        NULL    NULL    NULL
"10006""        ""1046395""     ""frwiki-20131107-pages-meta-history2.xml""     ""LoveBot""
        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Am I wrong with my table creation syntax?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Same as the result but without quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve reproduced your issue and can confirm it.

But in my opinion the Serde works as expected, and can’t help you in that situation. Because quoteChar takes a character and not a string, it manages to remove one occurrence of the double quote, but not the second.

If it was able to take a string, and not a char, as a parameter, then you could do the removal of your double quotes with it.

I think that you will have to use a Regex Serde to load your file ([see an example here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/emr/getting-started-emr-load-data.html)), or do the cleaning post-loading directly in Hive.

Edit: I just opened a ticket [in GitHub](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde/issues/19) on that issue

Edit 2: I have a solution using the Regex Serde, not the most beautiful thing you are going to see today, but it works (as long as you don't have double quotes in your strings):

```
CREATE TABLE titi (
  field1 STRING,
  field2 STRING,
  field3 STRING,
  field4 STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
"input.regex" = "\"\"([^\"]*)\"\"\;\"\"([^\"]*)\"\"\;\"\"([^\"]*)\"\"\;\"\"([^\"]*)\"\"",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Which uses the following Regex (without the escape caracter): ""([^"]*)"";""([^"]*)"";""([^"]*)"";""([^"]*)""

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue with Hive 3.x version with csv SerDe. Following fix my issue (example):

```
create external table sample(id int,first_name string,last_name string,email string,gender string,ip_address string)
  row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"separatorChar" = ",",
"escapeChar" = "\\",
"quoteChar"= "\'"
)
stored as textfile
location '/tmp/serdes/';
```

Precisely saying, there should be a backslash in quoteChar value as show above.